# Android app stops working on mobile phone but works fine on emulator

Tags: java, android

I have created a simple app. It has no errors and the algorithm part works fluently on emulator as well as my phone. But as soon as i press the action bar back button it the app stops. I does not stop on the emulator and works fine but stops in my phone.
Phone OS Version: 4.0.4
Emulator OS Version: 4.2

I've added the @SuppressLint("NewApi") line as well.

OnCreate code(for action bar):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}
```

Another method in the activity:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Parent activity is defined in the AndroidManifest file as well:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.app.DisplayMessage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.app.MainActivity" >
         >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post the logcat's content

Comment: Try to remove the `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`, then set the minimum SDK to 15 in the manifest file and Eclipse will highlight the class/method you shouldn't be using for API 15 (your phone's), as the issue here is most likely because of that.

Comment: What is the exception thrown?